# ¿Puede alguien identificar esta palabra hablada?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, identificación-de-término

¿Qué palabra falta debajo en [esta grabación](https://1drv.ms/u/s!At8Jnu5p-fSJj4UVwDK4Zbyadb_77w)?

> Si se quema antes de terminar la _____?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[cocción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9YoeniJ)**
>
> Del lat. *coctio, -ōnis*.
>
> 1. f. Acción y efecto de cocer o cocerse.

Tiene pinta de que están dando instrucciones para elaborar una receta, o algún truco o consejo de cocina.